# Join select statements to get columns in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(Type) from House where Type = 1
SELECT COUNT(Type) from House where Type = 2
SELECT COUNT(Type) from House where Type = 3
```

My question is: I want to join the above 3 statements to get: 3 columns i.e. eg:
ColumnType1: '50', ColumnType2: '60', columnType3: '45'

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
  count(case when Type = 1 then Type end) as type_1,
  count(case when Type = 2 then Type end) as type_2,
  count(case when Type = 3 then Type end) as type_3
from House
```

Comment: Hi I need your help. I have created a [dynamic query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10bc2/17) which works fine. But it [doesn't work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff09/1) when there is a *space* in the dynamic value (i.e. *channel* `unknown 01` in this example). Any solutions?

Comment: @hims056 You are better off wrapping the column names with backticks -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff09/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` and add up if the `Type` matches

```
SELECT sum(case when Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
       sum(case when Type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as type_2,
       sum(case when Type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as type_3
from House
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner type of SQL which can give you this answer, but you will have each type on a different row:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) FROM House GROUP BY Type
```

It has the disadvantage of not giving you columns as you asked for; but the advantage is that it works for any number of different types without needing to change the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Type) as val1,
    (SELECT COUNT(Type) from House where Type = 2) as val2,
    (SELECT COUNT(Type) from House where Type = 3) as val3
from House where Type = 1
```